# Current density of given current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-current, charge, density

Given is the current $I(t)=I_0\cos(wt)$ on a thin line on the $z$-axis from $z=[-l,l]$. I guessed now that the current density must be $\vec{j}(t)=\delta(x)\delta(y)I_0\cos(wt)\hat{e}_z$. But im not sure because this would mean that $j$ is the same on every point on the line. So not dependent on the position.
But if we assume a source at $-l$ with the current $I(t)$ then it would sometimes let go more charges per second and sometimes less. So the charge density of the line would be dependent of the location. Thats why i think the current density is also dependend of the position (because you can calculate the current density with the charge density).

Comment: Hello Peter, If you have that current in the line $[-l. l]$, then you should have a factor $H(l- z)H(z - l) / 2l$ in your density that where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. Then the density does depend on the position. What is your question? As you didn't put one it seems like just a statement.